# Can't save local characters on ClearDB (Heroku)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, heroku

I have Spring 4 Hibernate deployed to Heroku with ClearDB (MySQL) as database.

The problem is that can't use Polish characters as they are being replaced with "?".

If I run the project locally with local DB everything works fine. Also if I connect to that remote ClearDB with MySQL Workbench I am able to save with Polish characters as well so I guess the problem lies between Hibernate and the remote DB.

Here are my configuration files:

**App Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "kamienica.*")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    ReadingEnergyConverter readingEnergyConverter;
    @Autowired
    ReadingGasConverter readingGasConverter;
    @Autowired
    ReadingWaterConverter readingWaterConverter;
    @Autowired
    InvoiceGasConverter invoiceGasConverter;
    @Autowired
    InvoiceWaterConverter invoiceWaterConverter;
    @Autowired
    InvoiceEnergyConverter invoiceEnergyConverter;

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    }

    /*
     * Configure ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
        // Define all possible view resolvers
        List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();
        resolvers.add(jsonViewResolver());
        resolvers.add(viewResolver());
        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        // viewResolver.setContentType("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }

//  @Bean
//  public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
//      SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
//      localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH); // change this
//      return localeResolver;
//  }
//  
//  
//    @Override
//    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
//        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
//    }
//
//    @Bean
//    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
//        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
//        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
//        return localeChangeInterceptor;
//    }

    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(){
        return new CookieLocaleResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jsonViewResolver() {
        return new JsonViewResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(readingEnergyConverter);
        registry.addConverter(readingGasConverter);
        registry.addConverter(readingWaterConverter);
        registry.addConverter(invoiceEnergyConverter);
        registry.addConverter(invoiceGasConverter);
        registry.addConverter(invoiceWaterConverter);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }



    }
```

**Hibernate Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "kamienica.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired(required=false)
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "kamienica.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.charSet"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
```

**Resources for Hibernate:**

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://**************
jdbc.username = **************
jdbc.password = *******************
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>kamienica</groupId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Kamienica</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
        <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for rest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>

        <plugins>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>Kamienica</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.24.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <finalName>Kamienica</finalName>
    </build>
    <artifactId>Kamienica</artifactId>
</project>
```

Appreciate your help,
Maciej

Comment: Can you check that the platform is setting `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` by running this command: `heroku run echo \$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`?

Comment: The result of the command is:
Running echo $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS on macfol... up, run.7181

Comment: oh, i don't think that env var gets set in a one-off dyno. Do you see a line in your logs that says something like `Picking up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`? Does it contain the UTF-8?

Comment: Just saw this in logs:
Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 17040 target/Kamienica.war`

2016-02-29T20:58:47.243713+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.

2016-02-29T20:58:47.247540+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

2016-02-29T20:58:47.512202+00:00 app[web.1]: Adding Context  for target/Kamienica.war

Comment: Ok, it's there. And you have tried connecting from your local app to the Heroku DB? And it works correctly?

Comment: If connect through MySQL workbench everything works fine so I don't think the problem lies in ClearDB itself..

Comment: You could try it with JawsDB instead https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb

Comment: I'll try that if nothing else will work. Thanks :)